# How to get file list + permission statistics + analyze for uncommon permissions + finally batch change certain permissions to other permissions?

Tags: permissions, find, regular-expression, recursive

I copied some legacy files/folders from `/srv/my-old-disk/_oldstuff/` to `/srv/my-normal-disk/_oldstuff`.

How do I get this analysis for `/srv/my-old-disk/_oldstuff/` ?

How do I then change certain file types (file, dir, link) with a certain unwanted permission (e.g. 400) set to a desired permission set (e.g. 644) in a batch?

Answer (score 0):

## find & sort + uniq -c & perl RegEx

[image: File permissions batch change]

### 0) Create the necessary analysis file(s)

- A) Get listing with find and certain -printf flags
- B) Get stats with sort + uniq -c
- C) Get listing with files/dirs NOT having "normal" permissions with

  ```bash
  $ cd /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-f0233da3-473e-450d-9a18-b2ae254fc439/_get/_move

  $ find . -printf "%m %y %p\n" > ~/filelist-1a-perms-type-path-findraw.txt

  $ cat ~/list-perms-type-path-findraw.txt | sort > ~/filelist-1b-perms-type-path-sorted.txt

  $ find . -printf "%m %y\n" > ~/filelist-1c-perms-type-findraw.txt

  $ find . ~/filelist-1c-perms-type-findraw.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort > ~/filelist-1d-perms-type-extraordinary.txt

  $ perl -ne 'print if /^(?!755 |644 )/' ~/filelist-1b-perms-type-path-sorted.txt ~/filelist-1f-perms-type-path-extraordinary.txt
  ```
- Then you get these following files with the following exemplary content.

---

### ~/filelist-1a-perms-type-path-findraw.txt

- The raw output by find.
- Note that find does not traverse in lexicographical order, but by logic of the filesystem (comment appreciated, if anyone can explain exactly how).

  ```
  755 d .
  644 f ./Installers-Notes.txt
  644 f ./Installers-Bootdisk.txt
  755 d ./Software
  755 d ./Software/Multiplatform
  644 f ./Software/Multiplatform/.DS_Store
  644 f ./Software/Multiplatform/somesfiles.tgz
  755 d ./Software/Multiplatform/Some Extensions
  644 f ./Software/Multiplatform/Some Extensions/.DS_Store
  644 f ./Software/Multiplatform/Some Extensions/some_plugin.xpi
  ...
  ```

### ~/filelist-1b-perms-type-path-sorted.txt

- Sorted from leftmost to rightmost column
- First by permissions, then by type (file, dir, link, etc), then by filepath.
- You could also create a different sorting order if needed.

  ```
  444 f ./Software/Mac/Software1.zip
  444 f ./Software/Mac/Software5.cdr
  444 f ./Software/Mac/Software7.zip
  ...

  640 f ./Software/Mac/Software2.dmg
  640 f ./Software/Mac/Software3/Software3.dmg
  640 f ./Software/Mac/Software4.zip
  640 f ./Software/Mac/Software6.dmg
  640 f ./Software/Mac/Software7.zip
  ...
  ```

### ~/filelist-1c-perms-type-findraw.txt

- 1c is just an auxillary file for the generation of 1d.
- You could also skip it by piping right away.
- But for long listings which take long, I prefer to have the intermediary files, should I do a mistake somewhere, I do not need to generate from scratch again.
- You can later through this away ofc.

  ```
  755 d
  644 f
  644 f
  755 d
  755 d
  644 f
  644 f
  755 d
  644 f
  644 f
  644 f
  ```

### ~/filelist-1d-perms-type-extraordinary.txt

- This file gives you some statistics.
- Based on this you decided which uncommon files/folders you want listed in your 1f "extraordinary" analysis file, and shape the RegEx accordingly.

  ```
        2 555 f
        6 700 d
        7 645 f
       13 600 f
       20 444 f
       22 700 f
       57 640 f
      124 744 f
      423 777 l
    12315 755 d
    35606 755 f
    60759 644 f
  ```

### ~/filelist-1e-perms-type-extraordinary-annotated.txt

- This is just a dupe of 1d plus remarks of your research/thoughts.

  ```
  # Files:
        2 555 f
        7 645 f
       13 600 f
       20 444 f # Your remark here why this perms good/bad
       22 700 f
       57 640 f
      124 744 f
    35606 755 f
    60759 644 f

  # Directories:
        6 700 d
    12315 755 d

  # Links:
      423 777 l
  ```

### ~/filelist-1f-perms-type-path-extraordinary.txt

- This file helps you to analyze and later maybe take action, like batch change the permissions.
- You got this file with the line starting with `perl -ne 'print if /^(?!755 |644 )/'`
- Explanation of the regular expression:

  - Line start `^`
  - Is not followed by `(?!expression)` this is the so called negative lookahead
  - And the expression is `755`  `|` (logical or) `644`
  - Note the space after the numbers is not necessary as their are no 4-digit permission expressions such as "7550" which it could mismatch. Nevertheless I feel extra certain with this.

    ```
    444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File1.bom
    444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/Fil2.pax.gz
    444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File3/Contents/PkgInfo
    444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File3/Contents/File1.sizes
    444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File3/Contents/File2.plist
    444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File3/Contents/File3.info
    ...


    555 f ./Software/Mac/CategoryA/SoftwareB/README.txt
    555 f ./Software/Mac/_Audio Production Software/Propellerheads Reason 5/Source.nfo
    555 f ./Software/Mac/CategoryA/SoftwareC/Source.nfo
    ...
    ```
- This filelist should help you which directories/files maybe need adaptation.
- You could also then use find to selectively find file entries of a certain type (file/dir/link) and with certain permission(s), and then change those to a desired other permission.

### Find files/folders with a certain permission set and change them to another permission set

Let's say you want to change all files with permissions 444 to 644.

#### 1) Let's print all files of a certain undesired permission set

```
$ find . -type f -perm 444 -printf "%m %y %p\n"
```

- `-type f`  to only find files
- `-perm 444` which have permission 444
- `-printf` to get proper output for controlling what we are doing.

  - Note that `printf` should be **after** all filter criteria
  - Otherwise if will print what it encountered so far, but not what will remain after applying the next chain of filter(s).

```
444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File1.bom
444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/Fil2.pax.gz
444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File3/Contents/PkgInfo
444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File3/Contents/File1.sizes
444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File3/Contents/File2.plist
444 f ./Software/Mac/SoftwareA/File3/Contents/File3.info
...
```

#### 2) Now let's change them in batch

```
$ find . -type f -perm 444 -printf "%m %y %p\n" -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

- We added `-exec chmod 644 {} \;` at the end
- On each file that makes it through the filter criteria execute `chmod 644`
- You should get exactly the same listing as in the previous step (if the file contants have not changed since then).
- If you encounter errors you would get them additionally.

#### 3) Finally check that it was performed well

```
$ find . -type f -perm 444 -printf "%m %y %p\n"
```

- Same command line as in step 3
- This time it should return NULL (no file listing) because there should be no more files with 444 below the path where we applied find (which was `.` our then current working directory)